# Does using the WordPress get_results() database function prevent sql injection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, security, sql-injection

Couldn't seem to find a answer but wondering if the following query to the database is vulnerable to sql injection.

```
$searchPostResults = $wpdb->get_results($querySearchVals, OBJECT);
```

This is the query which is used:

```
global $wpdb;
$offset = (isset($_POST["moreSearchResults"])) ? $_POST["searchOffset"] : 0;

$querySearchVals = "
    SELECT DISTINCT post_title, ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
    WHERE (";

$sVals = array();
$sVals = explode(" ", $searchVal);

$lastIndex = intval(count($sVals)) - 1;
$orderByCaseVals = "";
for($i = 0; $i<count($sVals);$i++)
{
    $querySearchVals .= " post_title LIKE '%$sVals[$i]%' ";
    if($i != $lastIndex)
        $querySearchVals .= " OR ";

    $orderByCaseVals .= " WHEN post_title LIKE '%$sVals[$i]%' THEN ($i + 2) ";
}

$querySearchVals .= ") 
    AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN post_title LIKE '%$searchVal%' THEN 1
        $orderByCaseVals
    END
    LIMIT $offset, 6;
";
```

Cheers

Comment: What is the query? Injection occurs with string interpolation or concatenation, but `$querySearchVals` could contain anything here, so...maybe?

Comment: @tadman I have added the query for you, thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah, this thing is wide open and super full of holes. Use placeholder values for *any and all* user data.

Comment: Ok thanks tadman i thought so, how would I do the following code for like statement `$wpdb->prepare(" post_title LIKE '%%s%' ", $sVals[$i])`

Comment: @tadman nvm I got it with `$wpdb->prepare(" post_title LIKE '%s' ", "%" . $sVals[$i] . "%");`

Comment: Yeah, that's one step closer, butnormally placeholder values are specified without surrounding quotes as the escaping mechanism should introduce those if necessary.

Comment: Oh ok so I should probably do it with the esc like function `$wpdb->prepare(" post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' ", $wpdb->esc_like( $sVals[$i] ));` like suggested here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement

Comment: Also if I build a select statement which uses no user data, so the query is all my own code I gather I won't need to use the prepare statement? and how about if the data is part of an ajax call?

Comment: Ideally you construct a prepared statement with placeholder values. If you can't do that, then you need to manually escape each thing *very carefully*.

Comment: @tadman I have posted an answer, please let me know if it's not done corretly. Thanks for your help champ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as tadman explained the get_results does not prevent the sql injection attack.

the prepare function needs to be used.

I have re written the above code to prevent sql injection:

```
global $wpdb;
$offset = (isset($_POST["moreSearchResults"])) ? $_POST["searchOffset"] : 0;

$querySearchVals = "
    SELECT DISTINCT post_title, ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
    WHERE (";

$sVals = array();
$sVals = explode(" ", $searchVal);

$lastIndex = intval(count($sVals)) - 1;
$orderByCaseVals = "";
for($i = 0; $i<count($sVals);$i++)
{
    $queryPrep = $wpdb->prepare(" post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' ", $wpdb->esc_like( $sVals[$i] ));
    $querySearchVals .= $queryPrep;
    if($i != $lastIndex)
        $querySearchVals .= " OR ";

    $queryPrep = $wpdb->prepare(" WHEN post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' THEN ($i + 2) ", $wpdb->esc_like( $sVals[$i] ));
    $orderByCaseVals .= $queryPrep;
}

$querySearchVals .= ") 
    AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    ORDER BY CASE";

$queryPrep = $wpdb->prepare(" WHEN post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' THEN 1 ", $wpdb->esc_like( $searchVal ));
$querySearchVals .= $queryPrep;
$querySearchVals .= "
        $orderByCaseVals
    END
";

$queryPrep = $wpdb->prepare(" LIMIT %d, 12", $offset);
$querySearchVals .= $queryPrep . ";";
```

Comment: `LIMIT $offset` is not safe either.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is that because the $offset value comes from $_POST var

Comment: That doesn't make it safe.  It is not safe to concatenate anything into a query that has ever been out of your possession.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot How would I make the above query safe,as it's quite a complex query construction. I read up on another post that what I done above would be fine

Comment: It's not really all that complex if you step back from it. 
I would use  `LIKE CONCAT('%',%s,'%')`.  You can simplify building the query starting with `WHERE (1 = 0` and for each condition, append `OR` + next expression and append `)` at the end of the list.  The optimizer will throw away the test of 1 = 0, so it has no performance impact, but it makes building the query much simpler.  Push your parameters into an array, and use that array to execute the prepared statement.