# API error - A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress Version 4.9.6 and trying to create the following API:

However, when accessing the api via

http://localhost/demo_wordpress_api/wp-json/product/v1/manageproduct?category=computer

Find below my minimum viable example:

```
<?php
add_action('rest_api_init', 'productRoutes');

function productRoutes()
{
    register_rest_route('product/v1', 'manageproduct', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'allproductitability',
    ));
}

function allProductsByCategory($data)
{
    global $wpdb;

    // show db errors
    $wpdb->show_errors(true);
    $wpdb->print_error();

    // $data['term']

    $mainQuery = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *
    FROM wp_product_API
    WHERE id IN(
        SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM wp_product_API
        WHERE category = \" " + $data['category'] + " \"
        GROUP BY id)  
    ORDER BY price DESC
    LIMIT 1;" );
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
```

I get the error where I am inserting my parameter into my SQL Query:

```
    $mainQuery = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *
    FROM wp_product_API
    WHERE id IN(
        SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM wp_product_API
        WHERE category = \" " + $data['category'] + " \" // ON THIS LINE I GET THE ERROR
        GROUP BY id)  
    ORDER BY price DESC
    LIMIT 1;" );
```

Any suggestions why I get the error on this line?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Did you check that `$data` has a key named `category` ?

Comment: What type is `category` in your database?

Comment: @alanfcm `$category` is a `longtext` value in the db

Comment: @Med The value from the URL is correctly given. `$data` has a `category` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the wrong operator for concatenation.  In PHP `.` is what you should use like this:

```
$mainQuery = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *
FROM wp_product_API
WHERE id IN(
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM wp_product_API
    WHERE category = \" " . $data['category'] . " \" // ON THIS LINE I GET THE ERROR
    GROUP BY id)  
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1;" );
```

Comment: Thx! Any further suggestion how to make this query secure?

Comment: Here is a post on how to prevent sql injection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208353/does-using-the-wordpress-get-results-database-function-prevent-sql-injection